# In cdecl, is the callee required to preserve the arguments passed to it?

Tags: assembly, parameters, cdecl

Say I have `void f(int a, int b, int c) { g(a, b, c); h(a, b, c); }` in x86 assembly like this:

```
section .text
f:
    pop dword [res_1]
    call g          ; g(a, b, c)
    call h          ; h(a, b, c)
    push dword [res_1]
    ret
section .bss
res_1:
    resd 1
```

If `g` follows the cdecl calling convention, am I guaranteed that `g` will not alter the parameters passed to it in stack?

Comment: cdecl passes by value with a copy of the argument value on the stack frame.  It doesn't matter whether or not the caller "preserves" it, the copy is discarded after the call anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`cdecl` does not require callee to preserve it's arguments, but most functions do.

**Edit**: (add info / answer to comments)

(not relevant after the question has been edited) What about your code: the callee is not required to preserve `fpu` registers either.

I prefer to believe [Agner Fog](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf) with it, but you may try to find info in ABIs of your operating systems

Comment: You're right. Edited to acknowledge this. Do you have a source for your statement?